# Shortcut for super(type(self), self)

Tags: python

I often do this when overriding a method in a sub class:

```
def method_x(self):
    x = super(type(self), self).method_x()

    [Some extra code]
    return x
```

My question is: Is there a short cut for super(type(self), self) ?

Comment: Warning to anyone reading this: the above code is *wrong*.  Don't mimic it!

Comment: Glenn, Duncan: thanks for pointing out that this is wrong. I'll have to grep my code and change this.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: Not sure I understand why you consider it *wrong*. Would using `super(self.__class__, self)` be any better?

Comment: @martineau: No, that's no better.  `super`'s first argument is the *current* class in the inheritance chain, so super can figure out which class comes next.  Saying `type(self)` or `self.__class__` will give the *topmost* class, which will cause an infinite loop if that's a previous class.  See: http://pastebin.com/vhu5urCL

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: AH-HAH! Now I get it. Thanks for bearing with my density -- your reply coupled with the example code has finally made what's wrong crystal clear.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't do that: if `super` could just use `type(self)` as its first argument then it wouldn't have been written to take two arguments in the first place. You must pass the actual class here not an expression which could change if the class has been subclassed.

The first argument to super needs to be the class containing the current method definition as you are telling super where in the list of bases to start its search.

Python 3 knows about this and treats `super()` magically at compile time, but in Python 2.x it is just an ordinary function so it has no way to figure out those parameters for itself.

[Edit to add to my initial points]
Actually, there is another less used way to use `super()` in Python 2.x. You can use an unbound form of super and have it bound when you access it:

```
>>> class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print "A.foo"


>>> class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        self.__super.foo()
        print "B.foo"


>>> B._B__super = super(B)
>>> class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        self.__super.foo()
        print "C.foo"


>>> C._C__super = super(C)
>>> class D(C,B): pass

>>> D._D__super = super(D)
>>> D().foo()
A.foo
B.foo
C.foo
```

There is an important catch here: you have to use a different name to store each `super` object, which you can do by using `self.__super`, but you can't create an unbound `super` directly in the class definition (because you cannot name the class if it doesn't yet exist) and if you create it outside you have to manually obfuscate the name to ensure you set the correct `__super` object for the class. For Python 2.6 and later you could probably wrap this up as a class decorator.

Comment: I'd recommend against recommending this; it's not much of a win for doing something so unusual.

Comment: Yes, it's messy which is probably why it is less used, but I thought I should mention it as an option. A much better option of course is just to use Python 3.x (subject to it supporting whatever libraries you need)

Comment: I looked at using python3 today. I'm using Pylons Pyramid and it and some of it's dependencies don't support py3 yet, so I'll have to check back in a few months.