# How to make super() work by manually filling the __class__ cell?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, python-3.x, super

In Python 3 one can use `super()` instead of `super(MyClass, self)`, but this only works in methods that were defined inside the class. As described in [Michele Simionato's article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127) the following example does not work:

```
def __init__(self):
    print('calling __init__')
    super().__init__()

class C(object):
    __init__ = __init__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
```

It fails because `super()` looks for a `__class__` [cell](http://docs.python.org/c-api/cell.html), which is not defined in this case.

**Is it possible to set this cell manually after the function has been defined, or is that impossible?**

Unfortunately I don't understand how cells work in this context (didn't find much documentation for that). I'm hoping for something like

```
__init__.__class_cell_thingy__ = C
```

Of course I would only use this in a situation where the class assignment is unambiguous/unique (the whole process of adding methods to a class in is automatized in my case, so it would be simple to add such a line).

Comment: "Is it possible to set this cell manually"?  When you tried this, what happened?

Comment: But how can I get access to this cell after defining the function? `__init__.__class__` is of course something else. I have now edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Why do you want to define the function outside of the class? You'd want this if you want to reuse a function, or use a function as a method multiple times. You can't do those things and use `super(...)` correctly. And if you're modifying a class at runtime, you can simply hardcode it.

Comment: @Rush: Obviously the use cases for this are somewhat complicated. In my case it's related to aspect oriented programming. The function is only added to one class, so I could hardcode it (but that isn't my question). If you think that what I ask is impossible then please explain why, and I'll be happy accept your answer.

Comment: @nikow: If you like aspect oriented programming, take a look at the zope component architecture, that does this.

Comment: If you want to do AOP, why not use decorators?

Comment: @Lennart: Thanks for the reference. I think AOP is used in quite a few Python projects. Unfortunately I didn't find anything directly related to my question.

Comment: @S.Lott: In the actual code I do use function decorators. But that doesn't help me with `super` calls inside the function, or does it?

Comment: @nikow: Well, it seems a better idea to call super() inside the class's own `__init__`, and then maybe wrap that init with a decorator instead.

Comment: @nikow: Rather than hypothetical AOP like this, it's probably better to open a new question with the specific aspect that seems to be part of `__init__`.  Often, it actually isn't part of `__init__`.  It's easier to work with specific, tangible use cases.

Comment: @S.Lott: It doesn't matter that I used the `__init__` method in my example (which I took from the referenced article). It seems to me that my question was fairly specific, and I got an excellent answer. So I don't really understand why I had to defend this question so much.

Comment: @nikow: "I don't really understand why I had to defend this question so much".  Let's think.  Choice 1: we all hate you.  Choice 2: the question could stand some improvement.  Choice 3: we're all total idiots.  Pick one.

Comment: @S.Lott: You are welcome to edit the question or make suggestions on how to improve it. Unfortunately I still don't understand your previous comment about the relevant `__init__`, so I wasn't able to consider it.

Comment: @nikow: "still don't understand your previous comment about the relevant __init__"  I apologize.  It was a *request* for a new question with a concrete, specific, tangible, detailed use case for why you'd even want to do this.

Comment: @S.Lott: Ah, I see. My use case is somewhat complex, as it would be only a little feature for an already existing AOP-style extension mechanism in a larger project. I just wanted to determine if it would be feasible to add automatic support for `super()` once the Python 3 transition is complete. Due to the nature and complexity of the suggested solution I don't think that it is worth it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Seriously: you really don't want to do this.

But, it's useful for advanced users of Python to understand this, so I'll explain it.

Cells and freevars are the values assigned when a closure is created.  For example,

```
def f():
    a = 1
    def func():
        print(a)
    return func
```

`f` returns a closure based on `func`, storing a reference to `a`.  That reference is stored in a cell (actually in a freevar, but which one is up to the implementation).  You can examine this:

```
myfunc = f()
# ('a',)
print(myfunc.__code__.co_freevars)
# (<cell at 0xb7abce84: int object at 0x82b1de0>,)
print(myfunc.__closure__)
```

("cells" and "freevars" are very similar.  Freevars have names, where cells have indexes.  They're both stored in `func.__closure__`, with cells coming first.  We only care about `freevars` here, since that's what `__class__` is.)

Once you understand that, you can see how super() actually works.  Any function that contains a call to `super` is actually a closure, with a freevar named `__class__` (which is also added if you refer to `__class__` yourself):

```
class foo:
    def bar(self):
        print(__class__)
```

(Warning: this is where things get evil.)

These cells are visible in `func.__closure__`, but it's read-only; you can't change it.  The only way to change it is to create a new function, which is done with the `types.FunctionType` constructor.  However, your `__init__` function doesn't have a `__class__` freevar at all--so we need to add one.  That means we have to create a new code object as well.

The below code does this.  I added a base class `B` for demonstrative purposes.  This code makes some assumptions, eg. that `__init__` doesn't already have a free variable named `__class__`.

There's another hack here: there doesn't seem to be a constructor for the cell type.  To work around that, a dummy function `C.dummy` is created which has the cell variable we need.

```
import types

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("base")

class C(B):
    def dummy(self): __class__

def __init__(self):
    print('calling __init__')
    super().__init__()

def MakeCodeObjectWithClass(c):
    """
    Return a copy of the code object c, with __class__ added to the end
    of co_freevars.
    """
    return types.CodeType(c.co_argcount, c.co_kwonlyargcount, c.co_nlocals,
            c.co_stacksize, c.co_flags, c.co_code, c.co_consts, c.co_names,
            c.co_varnames, c.co_filename, c.co_name, c.co_firstlineno,
            c.co_lnotab, c.co_freevars + ('__class__',), c.co_cellvars)

new_code = MakeCodeObjectWithClass(__init__.__code__)
old_closure = __init__.__closure__ or ()
C.__init__ = types.FunctionType(new_code, globals(), __init__.__name__,
    __init__.__defaults__, old_closure + (C.dummy.__closure__[0],))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
```

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer. It's nice to know how these things work. I think I'll take your advise and stick to the explicit `super` calls for now. Until Python 3 becomes predominant this is somewhat academic anyway.

Comment: Another trick is to define a function inside a another function with a single argument `__class__` and then return the inner function (or just its closure). Then you wouldn't need the dummy method there to create the closure, or you might as well define the actual method as such inner function. Another thing is that you might use a class container (probably with an auxiliary metaclass with methods hiding the magic) to store the functions, then you wouldn't have to create custom code objects with that scary call.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, but by would you? In both cases you need to somehow be explicit of which class it is, because the implicit way didn't work. Maybe you can set the cell explicitly somehow, but there is no reason to do that. Just pass in the parameters explicitly.

```
def __init__(self):
    print('calling __init__')
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

class C(object):
    __init__ = __init__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
```

(It's better if you can pass in the actual class directly, like so:

```
def __init__(self):
    print('calling __init__')
    super(C, self).__init__()

class C(object):
    __init__ = __init__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
```

But if you can that, you could put the `__init__` on `C` directly, so assume you can't.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what you suggest here is very wrong. You can't use `self.__class__` with `super`, as was recently exaplained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883822/shortcut-for-supertypeself-self

Comment: @nikow: Well, if you are going to subclass it you can get into problems, yes, if that subclass also uses super(). So you want to use the same `__init__` for many different classes (because otherwise you wouldn't have defined it outside of the class) and you don't know which clases, and you don't know if or how these classes are subclassed? In that case I would say you are solving the problem wrong. Can I suggest a class decorator, or a component architecture with adapters?

Comment: @Lennart: The added function is defined elsewhere following ideas from AOP, and this has worked pretty well in our project. In the real code these "aspects" are activated/deactivated at runtime, so using decorator classes is not really an option. I was just hoping that one could enable the simplified `super()` calls, after all they were added to Python 3 for a reason.

Comment: @nikow: Sure, I understand. It's just that calling super() from the added methods in your case seems to be a bad idea. Hence the suggestion of using adapters (that fulfill the same function of making code being defined somewhere else) or decorators. Since it's runtime, deocrators are out of the questions, but adapters isn't. You should really look at the Zope component Architecture, which is aspect oriented, even if it doesn't like to brag about it. :) But it's probably too late for an ongoing project, but you might get ideas.

Comment: Nono, it's some other stickle for "You aren't supposed to do that" theory of coding. Do what works. :)

Comment: @Lennart: I looked at some AOP frameworks and extension mechanisms before the original implementation. Of course understanding Zope is not exactly a quick and easy task :-) My first implementation actually used adapters, but overall that was more complicated than our current solution.

Comment: @nikow: Not Zope. The zope component architecture. It's just one small part of Zope. :) http://www.muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html

Comment: You should **never** use `self.__class__` to `super()`, because now if you subclass `C` you get an infinite loop. Either pass in the explicit class object, *or* provide a closure for `__class__`; `self.__class__` is the wrong reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function's dictionary.

```
def f(self):
    super(f.owner_cls, self).f()
    print("B")

def add_to_class(cls, member, name=None):
    if hasattr(member, 'owner_cls'):
        raise ValueError("%r already added to class %r" % (member, member.owner_cls))
    member.owner_cls = cls
    if name is None:
        name = member.__name__
    setattr(cls, name, member)

class A:
     def f(self):
         print("A")

class B(A):
     pass

add_to_class(B, f)

B().f()
```

You can even add another attribute `member_name` if you don't want to hardcode the name of the name of the member inside the function.

Comment: That would work, but I'm not sure if I would prefer it to the explicit solution with writing class. After all I *know* which class the method will belong to, I just want to benefit from the more convenient Python 3 `super()`.

Comment: If you're doing something like this in the first place, you probably want to be able to assign the function to more than one class.

Comment: @Glenn: Yes, you are right. While this isn't my primary use case I remembered that there are cases where this would be an issue.