# Using super without naming the class

Tags: python, class, super, python-2.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcut for super(type(self), self)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883822/shortcut-for-supertypeself-self)

Every example I've seen of using `super` in Python 2.x looks like this: `super(ClassName, self)`.

Is there any reason not to use `super(type(self), self)`?

Comment: as described in the dupe, python 3's super() does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic