# Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

In Python 3.x, [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#super) can be called without arguments:

```py
class A(object):
    def x(self):
         print("Hey now")

class B(A):
    def x(self):
        super().x()
```

```
>>> B().x()
Hey now
```

In order to make this work, some compile-time magic is performed, one consequence of which is that the following code (which rebinds `super` to `super_`) fails:

```py
super_ = super

class A(object):
    def x(self):
        print("No flipping")

class B(A):
    def x(self):
        super_().x()
```

```
>>> B().x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in x
RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found
```

Why is `super()` unable to resolve the superclass at runtime without assistance from the compiler? Are there practical situations in which this behaviour, or the underlying reason for it, could bite an unwary programmer?

... and, as a side question: are there any other examples in Python of functions, methods etc. which can be broken by rebinding them to a different name?

Comment: I'll let Armin do the explaining on this [one](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2010/1/7/pros-and-cons-about-python-3/). This is also another good [post](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/5/21/porting-to-python-3-redux/)

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/36993577/674039

Answer (score 228, accepted):

The new magic `super()` behaviour was added to avoid violating the D.R.Y. (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle, see [PEP 3135](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/). Having to explicitly name the class by referencing it as a global is also prone to the same rebinding issues you discovered with `super()` itself:

```
class Foo(Bar):
    def baz(self):
        return super(Foo, self).baz() + 42

Spam = Foo
Foo = something_else()

Spam().baz()  # liable to blow up
```

The same applies to using class decorators where the decorator returns a new object, which rebinds the class name:

```
@class_decorator_returning_new_class
class Foo(Bar):
    def baz(self):
        # Now `Foo` is a *different class*
        return super(Foo, self).baz() + 42
```

The magic `super()` `__class__` cell sidesteps these issues nicely by giving you access to the original class object.

The PEP was kicked off by Guido, who [initially envisioned `super` becoming a keyword](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006667.html), and the idea of using a cell to look up the current class [was also his](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006671.html). Certainly, the idea to make it a keyword was part of the [first draft of the PEP](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/007024.html).

However, it was in fact Guido himself who then [stepped away from the keyword idea as 'too magical'](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-June/008242.html), proposing the current implementation instead. He [anticipated that using a different name for `super()` could be a problem](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-June/008301.html):

> My patch uses an intermediate solution: it assumes you need `__class__`
>   whenever you use a variable named `'super'`. Thus, if you (globally)
>   rename `super` to `supper` and use `supper` but not `super`, it won't work
>   without arguments (but it will still work if you pass it either
>   `__class__` or the actual class object); if you have an unrelated
>   variable named `super`, things will work but the method will use the
>   slightly slower call path used for cell variables.

So, in the end, it was Guido himself that proclaimed that using a `super` keyword did not feel right, and that providing a magic `__class__` cell was an acceptable compromise.

I agree that the magic, implicit behaviour of the implementation is somewhat surprising, but `super()` is one of the most mis-applied functions in the language. Just take a look at all the misapplied [`super(type(self), self)`](https://searchcode.com/?q=super%28type%28self%29+lang%3APython) or [`super(self.__class__, self)`](https://searchcode.com/?q=super%28self.__class__+lang%3APython)  invocations found on the Internet; if any of that code was ever called from a derived class [you'd end up with an infinite recursion exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208683/when-calling-super-in-a-derived-class-can-i-pass-in-self-class). At the very least the simplified `super()` call, without arguments, avoids *that* problem.

As for the renamed `super_`; just reference `__class__` in your method *as well* and it'll work again. The cell is created if you reference either the `super` **or** `__class__` names in your method:

```
>>> super_ = super
>>> class A(object):
...     def x(self):
...         print("No flipping")
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def x(self):
...         __class__  # just referencing it is enough
...         super_().x()
... 
>>> B().x()
No flipping
```

Comment: Good write-up.  It's still as clear as mud however.  You are saying that super() is equivalent to an automatically instantiated function like `def super(of_class=magic __class__)` kind of like a `self.super(); def super(self):  return self.__class__`?

Comment: @CharlesMerriam: This post is not about how `super()` without arguments works; it mostly deals with the *why* it exists. `super()`, in a class method, is equivalent to `super(ReferenceToClassMethodIsBeingDefinedIn, self)`, where `ReferenceToClassMethodIsBeingDefinedIn` is determined at compile time, attached to the method as a closure named `__class__`, and `super()` will look up both from the calling frame at runtime. But you don't actually need to know all this.

Comment: @CharlesMerriam: but `super()` is nowhere close to being an *automatically instantiated function*, no.

Comment: I just opened a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/48691652/1236579 that was closed as an exact duplicate. However, I don't understand how it can be considered a duplicate for reasons I included in an update and a comment for that post. It could be that I don't understand something. Can someone read my question, comment, and update empathetically and either tell me what I'm missing or validate that it shouldn't really be a dupe?

Comment: @chris.leonard: the key sentence is *The cell is created if you use super() or use `__class__` in your method*. You used the name `super` in your function. The compiler sees that and adds the `__class__` closure.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I see. I did not understand the bit about the cell. Now I know what to read up on and can make progress. Thank you all for helping with what was, in hindsight, an unnecessary question.

Comment: "Having to explicitly name the class by referencing it as a global" -- but why? It is enough to use `type(self)`, as everywhere else.

Comment: @Alexey: it is **not** enough. `type(self)` gives the **current** type, which is not the same as the type the method is defined on. So a class `Foo` with method `baz` needs `super(Foo, self).baz()`, because it could be subclassed as `class Ham(Foo):`, at which point `type(self)` is `Ham` and `super(type(self), self).baz()` would give you an infinite loop. See the post I link to in my answer: [When calling super() in a derived class, can I pass in self.\_\_class\_\_?](//stackoverflow.com/q/18208683)

Comment: This seems ok to me, this is what inheritance does. In this example, isn't `super(type(self), self).baz()` exactly what you want to call?

Comment: @Alexey: it only **looks** enough if you don't subclass. That's deceptive, and a common error to make because it only blows up when you do subclass. Try out the code in [the other post I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208683/when-calling-super-in-a-derived-class-can-i-pass-in-self-class) and you'll see why you can't use `type(self)`.