# Python: who owns the argument passed to super(args).__init__()

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, pyqt

according to inheritance in python, to override the constructor and at the same time implement it, you use something like this

```
class Dog :
    def __init__(self, name) :
        self.name = name 
        print("This is a dog named {}".format(self.name))

class Bingo(Dog) :
    def __init__(self, name) :
        super().__init__(self.name)
```

But I notice in some code I came across, super itself carry argument like,

```
    super(self, name).__init__()
```

so if I may ask, where is the argument passed to, is it the parent class or what. I find it hard to wrap my head on this, I actually encountered it on code in PyQt and PySide

Comment: `super()` is most likely from `Python 3.x` code, where arguments are optional. In `Python 2.x`, you had to write `super(<class object>,<class instance>)` to get the same effect. But in both cases, you pass the arguments to the `___init__` to the constructor itself (i.e. `__init__(<init args>)`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic)

Comment: `self` and `name` are arguments to the `super()` object, and are actually the wrong arguments to pass in. The first argument must be a type (so the class), the second must be an instance of the first argument.

Comment: note: `super().__init__(self.name)` in your code is wrong anyway, since the object does not have a `name` attribute when that line is called (since the attribute is created in `Dog.__init__` which hasn't been called yet).

Comment: I realize that the duplicate I linked you to is rather technical, but it does spell out the reasons for why there is a `super()` form, and why it exists compared to the `super(ClassObject, self)` form.

Comment: Thanks all, now I get it

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x you would have had to write

```
class Bingo(Dog) :
    def __init__(self, name) :
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name)
```

because `super` required the superclass name (`Dog`) and the instance (`self`). The super's `__init__` is `Dog.__init__` so would typically come from `Bingo.__init__` args (such as name), not as you had it (self.name, incorrect since doesn't exist yet).

In Python 3.0 you can write

```
class Bingo(Dog) :
    def __init__(self, name) :
        super().__init__(name)
```

because `super()` was given extra behavior that allows it to figure out `Dog` and `self` for you.