# How can a class that inherits from list and uses keyword arguments be made to work in both Python 2 and Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I have a class something like the following that works in Python 3. How can I get it to work also in Python 2?

```
class Palette(list):

    def __init__(
        self,
        name        = None, # string name
        description = None, # string description
        colors      = None, # list of colors
        *args
        ):
        super().__init__(self, *args)   
        self._name          = name
        self._description   = description
        self.extend(colors)

    def name(
        self
        ):
        return self._name

    def set_name(
        self,
        name = None
        ):
        self._name = name

    def description(
        self
        ):
        return self._description

    def set_description(
        self,
        description = None
        ):
        self._description = description

palette1 = Palette(
    name   = "palette 1",
    colors = [
        "#F1E1BD",
        "#EEBA85",
        "#E18D76",
        "#9C837E",
        "#5B7887"
    ]
)

palette1.set_description("This is palette 1.")

print(palette1.name())
print(palette1.description())
print(palette1)
```

Comment: Not about the issue: man, that style of argument formatting is next to unreadable; at least follow PEP8 and indent those arguments one level further.

Comment: Could you narrow it down a bit: **what does it currently do on Python 2?** Also, what's with the getters and setters? Are you unaware of `@property`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to change your `super()` call to use explicit arguments:

```
super(Palette, self).__init__(*args)
```

and your code will work just fine in both Python 2 and Python 3. See [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic) for background information on why the above is equivalent to `super().__init__(*args)`. Also, do *not* pass in `self` again, or you'll create a circular reference as you include `self` in the contents of the list.

Note that it is more pythonic use `property` objects instead of explicit getters and setters:

```
class Palette(list):
    def __init__(self, name=None, description=None, colors=None, *args):
        super(Palette, self).__init__(args)   
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.extend(colors)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._name = name

    @name.deleter
    def name(self):
        self.name = None

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self._description

    @description.setter
    def description(self, description):
        self._description = description

    @description.deleter
    def description(self):
        self.description = None
```

then use

```
palette1.description = "This is palette 1."
```

I also took the liberty of reducing the amount of whitespace in the function definitions; putting each and every argument on a new line makes it very hard to get an overview of the class as function bodies are needlessly pushed down.

As these properties don't actually *do* anything other than wrap an attribute by the same name with an underscore, you may as well just *leave them out altogether*. Unlike Java, in Python you can freely switch between using attributes directly, and later on swapping attributes out for a property object; you are not tied into one or the other.

Note that in both Python 2 and Python 3, you cannot pass in positional arguments; the following doesn't work:

```
Palette('#F1E1BD', '#EEBA85', name='palette2')
```

because the first positional argument will be assigned to the `name` argument:

```
>>> Palette('#F1E1BD', '#EEBA85', name='palette2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```

To support that use case, you need to *not* name the keyword arguments in the signature, and only use `**kwargs`, then retrieve your keyword arguments from that. Pass in any positional arguments as *one argument* so that `list()` takes any number of positional arguments as the contents for the new list:

```
class Palette(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Palette, self).__init__(args)
        self.name = kwargs.pop('name', None)
        self.description = kwargs.pop('description', None)
        self.extend(kwargs.pop('colors', []))
        if kwargs:
            raise TypeError('{} does not take {} as argument(s)'.format(
                type(self).__name__, ', '.join(kwargs)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Palette(list):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         super(Palette, self).__init__(args)
...         self.name = kwargs.pop('name', None)
...         self.description = kwargs.pop('description', None)
...         self.extend(kwargs.pop('colors', []))
...         if kwargs:
...             raise TypeError('{} does not take {} as argument(s)'.format(
...                 type(self).__name__, ', '.join(kwargs)))
... 

>>> palette1 = Palette(
...     name   = "palette 1",
...     colors = [
...         "#F1E1BD",
...         "#EEBA85",
...         "#E18D76",
...         "#9C837E",
...         "#5B7887"
...     ]
... )
>>> palette2 = Palette("#F1E1BD", "#EEBA85", "#E18D76", "#9C837E", "#5B7887",
...                    name="palette 2")
>>> palette1
['#F1E1BD', '#EEBA85', '#E18D76', '#9C837E', '#5B7887']
>>> palette2
['#F1E1BD', '#EEBA85', '#E18D76', '#9C837E', '#5B7887']
>>> palette1.name
'palette 1'
>>> palette2.name
'palette 2'
>>> palette1.description = 'This is palette 1.'
>>> palette2.description = 'This is palette 2.'
>>> Palette(foo='bar', spam='eggs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in __init__
TypeError: Palette does not take foo, spam as argument(s)
```

Comment: I've removed my objections. I do appreciate your taking the time to explain correct but "just leave them out altogether" methods; thanks.