# How to evaluate string as boolean in return statement?

Tags: python, boolean, truthiness

I have a function like this in Python 3.4:

```
def is_value_valid(the_str):
    return len(the_str) != 0
```

There are of course other ways to write this, such as `return the_str != ""`. Are there more pythonic ways of writing this expression? I am familiar with the concepts of truthy/falsy, so I know I could shortcut this in an if condition:

```
if not the_str:
    # do stuff
```

But the `if` *expects* a boolean result in its expression (this is my naive oversimplification here as a C++ programmer; I'm not familiar with standardese for this). However, there is nothing there to force the expression to evaluate to boolean in the return statement. I have tried just returning the string, and as long as no one treats the returned value as a string, it works just fine in calling code under boolean context. But from a post-condition perspective, I don't want to return a non-boolean type.

Comment: `bool(the_str)`??

Comment: `if the_str:` would be the most Pythonic way to write it. It's not necessary to force the interpreter to cast the type. `if` does not _expect_ a boolean result in Python. In Python, `if` merely treats all results as boolean, whether they're boolean or not.

Comment: FWIW, `'foo' or 'bar'` does not return a boolean either. You may have to relax your definition of a *truthy value* for Python.

Comment: Why not simply `if not bool(the_str)` ?

Comment: @Burhan Why not simply `if not the_str`?

Comment: IMHO, the most Pythonic way would be to simply use the `if` statement. Why waste a function call for something so trivial? Unless, of course, this is just a simplified example.

Comment: I _truly_ do not understand the reasoning behind explicitly casting the value, and would appreciate clarification. (I gather that there's some attempt to explain it in the question, but I don't get it.)

Comment: @PM2Ring: because you can't return `if` statement. `if the_str: return True`, `else: return False` is far more overkill. And there may be much more in the function, what if that string was produced by an external call?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Understood. If the real code is more complex than what's in the OP, then sure, it may make sense to wrap this in a function. But if the real code is simply testing if a string is empty or not, then I think it's better to have a simple explicit `if` rather than calling a function.

Comment: @PM2Ring: *I have tried just returning the string, and as long as no one treats the returned value as a string, it works just fine in calling code under boolean context. But from a post-condition perspective, I don't want to return a non-boolean type.*. So the intention is for the function to return a boolean. Returning a string instead exposes an implementation detail of the function and returns the wrong type. `bool()` is *the only proper solution* for this use-case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sure. _If_ the OP really needs a function for this, then `bool()` is the proper solution. I'm just questioning the need for the `is_value_valid` function in the first place. I guess a compromise would be to call `bool()` inline, rather than having it hidden inside `is_value_valid`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what the [`bool()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) does; return a boolean based on evaluating the [truth value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of the argument, just like an `if` statement would:

```
return bool(the_str)
```

Note that `if` doesn't *expect* a boolean value. It simply evaluates the truth value of the result of the expression.

Comment: `return True if the_str else False`. I see the equivalent of this weird ternary idiom in PHP all the time. I just don't get why we're doing this exercise. :(

Comment: @kojiro: if a function promises to return a boolean, it is better to actually return a boolean. That makes for a cleaner interface.

Comment: Is that why? From the question, it sounds like the argument is that `if` _expects_ a boolean, not that a function promises it.

Comment: @kojiro: That's the *post-condition perspective*; the post-condition is an expectation about what a function does. The post-condition here is that a boolean is returned.

Comment: OK. I can accept this explanation, but I was definitely scratching my head at the level of effort for a while!

Comment: @kojiro `return $foo ? true : false` is terrible in any language. In PHP that should be `return (bool)$foo`, if anything.

Comment: @kojiro: There are loads of antipatterns in wide use, waiting to become bugs. Like [this one](https://searchcode.com/?q=super%28type%28self%29+lang%3APython) or [this one](https://searchcode.com/?q=super%28self.__class__+lang%3APython), see [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19609168). There are a lot of programmers out that that *don't understand their craft*.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> bool("foo")
True
>>> bool("")
False
```

Empty strings evaluate to `False`, but everything else evaluates to `True`. So this should not be used for any kind of parsing purposes.

So just `return bool(the_str)` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The if statement automatically evaluates a string as a boolean. However, if you want to return your string as a boolean you would simply do

```
return bool(the_str)
```

Comment: You are very late to this party. Why repeat what others have already stated 15 minutes ago?

Answer (score 0):

`bool(the_str)` is definitely the way to go, as several have mentioned.

**But if your method requires that a string be given**, I would also test for the string actually being a string (because `bool(5)` and `bool("this is a string")` will both return true.

```
return isinstance(the_str, str) and bool(the_str)
```

Or when used in an `if` statement:

```
if isinstance(the_str, str) and the_str:
    # here we are sure it's a string whose length > 0
```

Comment: In an `if` context, just use `isinstance(the_str, str) and the_str`; using `bool()` there is entirely redundant.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking about though. They are asking how to produce a boolean to return from a function. It is not about validating that the value tested is a string, only how to produce a boolean for the truth value.

Comment: I would argue it depends on context -- for some methods `return isinstance(the_str, str) and bool(the_str)` might be what's necessary

Comment: That would return `False` or the value of `the_str` again, so not always a boolean.

Answer (score -2):

```
def is_value_valid(the_str):
    return bool(len(the_str) != 0)
```

Using bool(x) converts the value to a boolean. This function takes `len(the_str) != 0`, evaluates it, converts it to bool, then returns the value.

The bool(x) is not required, you can just have the parentheses, because it will already return a bool, as evaluations return boolean by default.

Comment: `!=` already returns a `bool`, wrapping it again in `bool()` is entirely superfluous.