# Why does Python 2's `super` require explicit class and self arguments?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

[This Python 2 example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577720-how-to-use-super-effectively/):

```py
class LoggingDict(dict):
    # Simple example of extending a builtin class
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        logging.info('Setting %r to %r' % (key, value))
        super(LoggingDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

and [this Python 3 example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577720-how-to-use-super-effectively/):

```py
class LoggingDict(dict):
    # Simple example of extending a builtin class
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        logging.info('Setting %r to %r' % (key, value))
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

illustrate the fact that Python 2's `super` requires explicit class and `self` arguments (but Python 3's doesnt). Why is that? It seems like an irritating limitation.

Comment: May be you can find it here what you seek - [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic)

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question but does provide some useful context to chew over, maybe when I sit down and think about it an answer will present itself.

Comment: In fact, I think that question does hint at the answer: it's because 'compile-time magic' is performed, and also in the mention of the fact that `super(self.__class__...` is Bad. This requires some thought!

Comment: @Brendan Python3 breaks in some situations, e.g `def __init__(self): mysuper = super; mysuper().__init__()` will not call the parent class `__init__`, yet it's not a `SyntaxError`.  In fact I find that the Python3 implementation is too much a hack...I would have rather have `super` as a proper keyword...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in AKS' comment provides the answer here:

Lets say in the Python 2 example I thought "I don't like that explicit class reference. What if I change the name of the class or move this code and forget to update it?". Lets say I thought, a-ha, I'll replace the explicit class name with `self.__class__` and wrote:

```py
class LoggingDict(dict):
    # Simple example of extending a builtin class
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        logging.info('Setting %r to %r' % (key, value))
        super(self.__class__, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

Now I create a subclass called `SpecialisedLoggingDict` of `LoggingDict` (which doesn't override `__setitem__`), instantiate it and call `__setitem__` on it.

Now `self` refers to an instance of `SpecialisedLoggingDict`, so the `super` returns `LoggingDict`, and we go straight back into `LoggingDict.__setitem__`, entering infinite recursion.

The essential point is that in **Python 2 a method doesn't really know which class it was defined in, it only knows the class of the instance on which it's being called**. Python 3 [does compile-time "magic"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/), adding a `__class__` cell to functions so that `super()` can be used without the explicit class reference.