# where does `__class__` variable come from in methods?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

### I was surprised that I can use `__class__` unqualified inside methods!

*Given these facts:

1) `__class__` is not defined in either global or builtin scopes of the interactive session

2) Tested under Python 3.3.3 and Python 2.7.11

Example:

```
class Z: 
    def __init__(self):
        print(__class__)
```

Works under Python 3.3.3, but when tested with Python 2.7.11, this raises an error with classic and new-style classes. As usual when we want to use a variable defined inside a class we have to use `obj.attr`. surprisingly for `__class__` it just works!

```
class Z(object): 
    a = 20
    def __init__(self):
        print(__class__)
        print(a)            # doesn't work
```

**Where does `__class__` come from?**

**Is this a bug?**

Comment: This is a Python 3 feature, it is used by `super()`.

Comment: `__class__` is a *closure* added to make `super()` without arguments work. See the duplicate.

Comment: Also see [Schrödinger's variable: the \_\_class\_\_ cell magically appears if you're checking for it's presence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36993577)

Comment: Here comes the headache! Wouldn't be better if `super` is a keyword or removed totally?