# Importing modules within the same directory

Tags: python

Consider the following directory structure:

```
lib/
  markov.py
  solver.py
  test.py
```

`markov.py` has the following code: [super() throwing an error in Sublime Text, works in PyCharm/Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42819134/7073884)

`solver.py` only contains a bunch of mathematical functions, here's an example of one:

```
def mm1_busy_idle(arrival, service):
    return round(1 - (arrival / service), 4)
```

Now, when I try to do `import solver` in `markov.py`, PyCharm tells me that there's `No module named solver`. However, when I do `import test` it does it just well and I can run the test function from there:

```
def test():
    print("test!")
```

Also, when I hover over `test.test()` PyCharm shows me the following tooltip: `Cannot find reference 'test' in '__init__.py'`.

My question is: Why can I `import test` and run the function `test()` but I can't `import solver` in `markov.py`?

Comment: try `from . import solver `

Comment: @yosemite_k `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: `from lib import solver `

Comment: @yosemite_k That gives me `unresolved reference`

Answer (score 2):

add one file (__init__.py  empty file)  in lib,

```
lib/
  __init__.py
  markov.py
  solver.py
  test.py
```

An ultimate solution:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/lib")
```

Comment: Your proposed solution didn't really change much.