# How to detect if `__init_subclass__` has been overridden in a subclass?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Normally in Python, it is possible to detect whether a method has been overridden in a subclass using the following technique:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def mymethod(self): pass
...
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
...
>>> Bar.mymethod is Foo.mymethod 
True
```

The expression `Bar.mymethod is Foo.mymethod` will evaluate to `True` if the method from `Foo` has *not* been overridden in `Bar`, but will evaluate to `False` if the method *has* been overridden in `Bar`. This technique works well with dunder methods inherited from `object`, as well as non-dunder methods:

```
>>> Bar.__new__ is Foo.__new__
True
>>> Bar.__eq__ is Foo.__eq__
True
```

We can formalise this logic in a function like so:

```
def method_has_been_overridden(superclass, subclass, method_name):
    """
    Return `True` if the method with the name `method_name`
    has been overridden in the subclass
    or an intermediate class in the method resolution order
    """
    if not issubclass(subclass, superclass):
        raise ValueError(
            "This function only makes sense if `subclass` is a subclass of `superclass`"
        )
    subclass_method = getattr(subclass, method_name)
    if not callable(method):
        raise ValueError(f"'{subclass.__name__}.{method_name}' is not a method")
    return subclass_method is not getattr(superclass, method_name, object())
```

However, this technique fails when it comes to two methods: `__init_subclass__` and `__subclasshook__`:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
...
>>> Bar.__init_subclass__ is Foo.__init_subclass__
False
>>> Bar.__subclasshook__ is Foo.__subclasshook__
False
```

And, for an even more perplexing example:

```
>>> type.__init_subclass__ is type.__init_subclass__
False
```

I have two questions:

1. *Why* does this technique fail with these methods, and these methods only? (I have not been able to find any other examples where this technique fails -- but if there are any, I'd love to know about them!)
2. Is there an alternative technique that can be used to detect if `__init_subclass__` or `__subclasshook__` have been defined in a subclass after being left undefined in the superclass?

Comment: A way to check for override which is probably not guaranteed to work for all implementations is `Bar.__init_subclass__.__func__ is Foo.__init_subclass__.__func__`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Unfortunately, that doesn't even work for plain CPython and the simple `Foo` and `Bar` example classes in the question. classmethods written in C (like `object.__init_subclass__`) use different types from classmethods written in Python, and the types for C methods don't support `__func__`.

Comment: Related: [argument binding for dynamic `__init_subclass__` method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50137242/674039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__init_subclass__` is a special method, in that it is implicitly a `classmethod` even if you do not decorate it with `@classmethod` when defining it. However, the issue here does not arise from the fact that `__init_subclass__` is a special method. Instead, there is a fundamental error in the technique you are using to detect whether a method has been overridden in a subclass: it won't work with any `classmethod`s at all:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def mymethod(self): pass
...     @classmethod
...     def my_classmethod(cls): pass
...
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
...
>>> Bar.mymethod is Foo.mymethod
True
>>> Bar.my_classmethod is Foo.my_classmethod
False
```

This is because of how *bound methods* in Python work: methods, in Python, are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Observe the equivalence of the following lines of code with respect to instance methods. The first (more normal) way of calling `mymethod` on the instance `f` is merely syntactic sugar for the second way of calling the method on the instance `f`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def mymethod(self):
...         print('Instance method')
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.mymethod()
Instance method
>>> Foo.__dict__['mymethod'].__get__(f, Foo)()
Instance method
```

Calling `__get__` on the unbound method in `Foo.__dict__` produces a new object each time; it is only by accessing the instance method on the *class* that we can test for identity, as you do in your question. However, with regards to `classmethod`s, even accessing the method from the *class* will call `__get__` on the method:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @classmethod
...     def my_classmethod(cls):
...         print('Class method')
...
>>> Foo.my_classmethod is Foo.my_classmethod
False
>>> Foo.my_classmethod()
Class method
>>> Foo.__dict__['my_classmethod'].__get__(Foo, Foo)()
Class method
```

**What about `__new__`?**

Your question points out that your existing method works with `__new__`. That's strange -- we've just established that this method doesn't work with `classmethod`s, and `__new__` certainly *looks* like a `classmethod`. The first parameter of `__new__` is named `cls`, after all! However, the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) makes clear that this isn't the case at all:

> `object.__new__(cls[, ...])`
>
> Called to create a new instance of class `cls`. `__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) that takes the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument.

It's a `staticmethod`, not a `classmethod`! Mystery solved.

**A better way of detecting whether a subclass overrides a method from a superclass**

The only sure-fire way of knowing for sure if a method has been overridden in a subclass is by traversing the `__dict__` of each class in the method resolution order:

```
def method_has_been_overridden(superclass, subclass, method_name):
    """
    Return `True` if the method with the name `method_name`
    has been overridden in the subclass
    or an intermediate class in the method resolution order
    """
    if not issubclass(subclass, superclass):
        raise ValueError(
            "This function only makes sense if `subclass` is a subclass of `superclass`"
        )
    subclass_method = getattr(subclass, method_name)
    if not callable(subclass_method):
        raise ValueError(f"'{subclass.__name__}.{method_name}' is not a method")
    for cls in subclass.__mro__:
        if cls is superclass:
            return False
        if method_name in cls.__dict__:
            return True
```

This function can correctly determine whether or not `__init_subclass__`, or any other `classmethod`, has been overridden in a subclass:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
...
>>> class Baz(Foo):
...     def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...         return super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
>>> method_has_been_overridden(Foo, Bar, '__init_subclass__')
False
>>> method_has_been_overridden(Foo, Baz, '__init_subclass__')
True
```

---

*Many thanks to [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69787383/13990016) and [U12-Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69787411/13990016), whose excellent answers helped me figure this problem out.*

Answer (score 4):

`__init_subclass__` is special-cased to be a class method, whether you decorate it with `classmethod` or not. Just like `Foo().mymethod` returns a new `method` instance every time you access the attribute via a class instance, `Foo.__init_subclass__` produces a new `instance` method every time you access the attribute via the class itself.

`__subclasshook__`, on the other hand, *must* be declared as a class method to work properly. It is not assumed to be a class method if you define it as a simple function/instance method.

Answer (score 2):

`__init_subclass__` and `__subclasshook__` are class methods. As you can see here:

```
>>> Bar.__sizeof__
<method '__sizeof__' of 'object' objects>
>>> Bar.__eq__
<slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>
>>> Bar.__subclasshook__
<built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object at 0x000002D70AAC5340>
>>> Bar.__init_subclass__
<built-in method __init_subclass__ of type object at 0x000002D70AAC5340>
>>> Foo.__init_subclass__
<built-in method __init_subclass__ of type object at 0x000002D70AACAF70>
>>>
```

`__init_subclass__` and `__subclasshook__` refer to their classes that are different instances, `Bar`'s hex is `0x000002D70AAC5340`, and `Foo`'s hex is `0x000002D70AACAF70`.

---

As you can see in the documentation of [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__), it says:

> *classmethod* **object**.`__init_subclass__`(cls)

It says "classmethod".