# Why does assigning to the __class__ cell break `super`?

Tags: python, closures, super

I've read [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic) and understand that using `super` or `__class__` in a method will automagically create a `__class__` cell variable for that method:

```
class Demo:
    def meth(self):
        super().meth()
```

```
>>> Demo.meth.__closure__
(<cell at 0x7f4572056138: type object at 0x564bda0e5dd8>,)
>>> Demo.meth.__closure__[0].cell_contents
<class '__main__.Demo'>
```

And as far as I know, cells are used to hold closure variables and can be freely modified:

```
def outer():
    x = 3
    def inner():
        print(x)

    x = 5
    return inner

inner = outer()
inner()  # output: 5
```

```
>>> inner.__closure__
(<cell at 0x7f2183a5e138: int object at 0x7f2184600460>,)
```

But trying to reassign the value of the `__class__` cell makes `super` throw a strange error:

```
class Demo:
    def meth(self):
        __class__ = Demo
        super().meth()

Demo().meth()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 8, in <module>
    Demo().meth()
  File "untitled.py", line 6, in meth
    super().meth()
RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found
```

Why does this happen? Why can't `__class__` be reassigned like other closure variables?

Comment: This assignment is discussed in user2357112 answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36994027/674039): "The assignment to `__class__` means `__class__` is a local variable instead of a closure variable".  Dupe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `nonlocal` statement to assign to closure variables, including the magic `__class__` closure variable. Assigning to `__class__` without a `nonlocal` statement creates a local variable that hides the magic closure variable.

You're expecting `__class__` to behave as if it was local to `meth`, but it actually behaves as if it's local to an invisible pseudo-scope in which all methods of `Demo` are nested. If it was treated as local to `meth`, you wouldn't need `nonlocal`.

If you do add a `nonlocal` statement, the implementation [actually will allow you](https://ideone.com/sgnivW) to reassign the magic closure variable:

```
class Foo:
    def meth(self):
        nonlocal __class__
        __class__ = 3
        super()

Foo().meth()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "./prog.py", line 5, in meth
RuntimeError: super(): __class__ is not a type (int)
```