# Why __class__ can be directly accessed

Tags: python

I found this quirk while checking out how to use `super`.

```
In [1]: super?                                                                                                      
Init signature: super(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
super() -> same as super(__class__, <first argument>)
...
```

Note that the first example uses `__class__` directly.

And somehow, `__class__` can be used inside instance methods:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        print(__class__)
    def foo(self):
        print(__class__)
    def bar(self):
        print(bar)

t = Test()  # <class '__main__.Test'>
t.foo()  # <class '__main__.Test'>
t.bar()  # NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: @DYZ: No. For one thing, methods and variables defined in a class body are not accessible by bare name within method bodies. For another, `__class__` is not actually defined in the class body. (`Test.__class__` is a valid expression, but refers to something completely different. `self.__class__` is also a valid expression, but refers to something subtly different in a way that has caused many bugs.) This `__class__` is a weird special case used for `super` support.

Comment: Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993577/schr%C3%B6dingers-variable-the-class-cell-magically-appears-if-youre-checking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it is a quirk for the compiler to find the parent class.

From [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object):

> __class__ is an implicit closure reference created by the compiler if any methods in a class body refer to either __class__ or super. This
>   allows the zero argument form of super() to correctly identify the
>   class being defined based on lexical scoping, while the class or
>   instance that was used to make the current call is identified based on
>   the first argument passed to the method.