# How to initiate super in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to make this python 3 code python 2 compatible:

```
class AlarmThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, file_name="beep.wav"):
        super().__init__()
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.ongoing = None
```

I get this error when I try to use the class in python 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "plugin.py", line 144, in run
    alert_after_timeout(seconds, message)
  File "plugin.py", line 96, in alert_after_timeout
    thread = AlarmThread()
  File "plugin.py", line 78, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass in the *current class* and `self`:

```
super(AlarmThread, self).__init__()
```

Also see [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic) why and how Python 3 dropped the need to specify those.

Comment: As a heads up, you may get a TypeError using super.  The solution is to add "object" to the list of parent objects in the class definition.  So if  
"class MyClass(otherclass):" doesn't work, try: "class MyClass(otherclass,object):"

Comment: @RufusVS `super()` only works with new-style classes, yes.