# constructor with or without self?

Tags: python

I have a question about a program:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def to_string(self):
        return "x, y = (" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ")"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.to_string()


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, z, *args):
        A.__init__(self, *args)
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()


class C(A):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def to_string(self):
        return "Klasse C, " + super().to_string()
```

Why I have to write

```
A.__init__(self, *args)
```

instead of

```
A.__init__(*args)
```

In class C it works?
Lots of greetings

Comment: Please correct the indentation during declaration of class B and C

Comment: Note that the constructors of `B` and `C` are not the same. They use different methods for calling the base constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing the *unbound method*, so `self` is not passed in. There is no context for `A.__init__` to know what instance to bind to.

You have several options to provide that context:

- Pass in `self` explicitly, as you did.
- Bind manually, with `A.__init__.__get__(self)(*args)`
- In Python 3, use `super().__init__(*args)` and the context is then taken from the current method. See [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic)