# Python3 - using super() in __eq__ methods raises RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, super, overloading, monkeypatching

I am monkey patching the `__eq__` method of a class. I found that the following works:

```
   def eq(obj, other):
       if isinstance(other, str):
          return obj.name.upper() == other.upper()
       else:
          return object.__eq__(obj, other)
```

This does not work:

```
  def eq(obj, other):
     if isinstance(other, str):
         return obj.name.upper() == other.upper()
     else:
        return super().__eq__(other)
```

This sometimes works, but sometimes raises and error:

```
def eq(obj, other):
   if isinstance(other, str):
       return obj.name.upper() == other.upper()
   else:
       return super().__eq__(self, other)
```

The error:

```
<ipython-input-128-91287536205d> in eq(obj, other)
      3         return obj.name.upper() == other.upper()
      4     else:
----> 5         return super().__eq__(self, other)
      6 
      7 

RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found
```

Can you explain what is going on here? How do I properly replace `object` with `super()`?

Comment: There is no difference between your 'does not work' and 'sometimes works' examples, other than indentation. Both only 'sometimes' work as long as the `else` branch is not reached.

Comment: Note that `super(...).__eq__` is a *bound method*, so the first argument (usually named `self`) is automatically passed in from the second argument to `super(cls, instance)`. You only need to pass in `other`: `super(...).__eq__(other)`.

Comment: I've encountered this error while creating `__new__` outside of the class (dynamically, for tests purposes, you really don't need this kind of magic in actual code), using 2-arguments `super` call like `super(metaclass, cls).__new__(cls)` with `metaclass` almost always being just `type` solved the issue

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't use `super()` without arguments in a function defined outside of a class. The `__class__` cell `super()` relies on is only provided for functions defined in a `class` body. From the [`super()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super):

> The zero argument form only works inside a class definition, as the compiler fills in the necessary details to correctly retrieve the class being defined, as well as accessing the current instance for ordinary methods.

Use the 2-argument form, naming the class explicitly:

```
def eq(obj, other):
   if isinstance(other, str):
       return obj.name.upper() == other.upper()
   else:
       return super(ClassYouPutThisOn, obj).__eq__(other)

ClassYouPutThisOn.__eq__ = eq
```

This requires you to explicitly name the class in the monkey patch, making it less useful for reuse.

Instead, you can provide the required `__class__` cell *manually* by nesting `eq` in another function with `__class__` as a local name:

```
def patch_eq(cls):
    __class__ = cls  # provide closure cell for super()
    def eq(obj, other):
       if isinstance(other, str):
           return obj.name.upper() == other.upper()
       else:
           return super().__eq__(other)
    cls.__eq__ = eq
```

`super()` finds the second argument (reference to the instance), by taking the first local name from the calling frame (i.e. the first parameter passed into the function call, usually called `self`).

Also see [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic)

Demo using the nested-function approach:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     name = 'bar'
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return False
...
>>> Foo() == 'Bar'
False
>>> Foo() == Foo()
False
>>> patch_eq(Foo)
>>> Foo() == 'Bar'
True
>>> Foo() == Foo()
False
```