# Python dynamic update instance method

Tags: python, django

`admin` is instance. I want to do something to instance like decorator.

```py
class CodeInClass(admin.AdminSite):
    def get_app_list(self, request):
        all_list = super().get_app_list(request)
        # reorder the app list as you like
        return all_list


def get_app_list(request):
    all_list = super().get_app_list_old(request)
    # dosomething()
    return all_list

admin.site.get_app_list_old = admin.site.get_app_list
admin.site.get_app_list = get_app_list
```

Get error:

```py
RuntimeError at /admin/
super(): __class__ cell not found
```

Comment: What is `admin.AdminSite`? Is it a class?

Comment: Yes, admin.site = <django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite>

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778914/python3-using-super-in-eq-methods-raises-runtimeerror-super-class

Comment: Looks like the `super()` in `get_app_list` outside class definition is causing the issue

Comment: I tried `super(admin.AdminSite).get_app_list_old(request)`,   get error `'super' object has no attribute 'get_app_list_old`.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what exactly are you trying to achieve with this code. Can you may be try to elaborate little bit more in the question?