# What is the difference between super() and explicit super(Cl,self) (with __slots__ and attrs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, super, python-attrs

I'm using the `attrs` python package, in combination with inheritance and slots. I want to call the parent class's method from within the derived method. The problem is demonstrated below:

```
import attr

@attr.s(slots=True)
class Base():
    def meth(self):
        print("hello")

@attr.s(slots=True)
class Derived(Base):
    def meth(self):
        super().meth()
        print("world")

d = Derived()
d.meth()
```

I get:

> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

The problem seems to be triggered by a combination of attrs (undecorated classes with explicit `__slots__=()` work), slots (regular `@attr.s`-decorated classes work) and the plain `super()` call (`super(Derived, self)` works).

I would like to understand how `super()` behaves differently from the explicit `super(Derived, self)` version, since the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super) says they "do the same thing"

Comment: This has since been fixed in attrs: https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/pull/226

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super()` normally relies on the compiler to provide a `__class__` closure cell, that is bound to the class object a method is derived on. The closure is created the moment you use the name `super()` in a method (or if you used `__class__`):

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def bar(self):
...         super()  # just using super or __class__ is enough
...
>>> Foo.bar.__closure__[0].cell_contents
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo.bar.__closure__[0].cell_contents is Foo
True
```

That closure lets `super()` work without arguments (the `self` argument is taken from the local namespace).

However, `attr` generates a *new class object* when you specify you wanted to use `__slots__`; you can't add slots to a class after the fact, so a [new class object is created](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/4faf5f9c265fe9cd093ff6f866d63c1b2962b91b/src/attr/_make.py#L382-L394) that replaces the one you decorated.

The closure attached to `meth` is the original pre-decoration class and not the same class object as the new generated class:

```
>>> Derived.meth.__closure__[0].cell_contents
<class '__main__.Derived'>
>>> Derived.meth.__closure__[0].cell_contents is Derived
False
```

This breaks the expectations `super()` has, making it impossible to use the 0 argument variant. The `super(Derived, self)` variant explicitly looks up the name `Derived` as a global when called, finding the new generated class, so works.

I go into some more detail on how `super()` without arguments works, and why, in [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic/19609168#19609168)

This was reported as [issue #102](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/102) in the tracker, and *fixed* by altering the closure with some [`ctypes` hackery](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/master/src/attr/_compat.py#L98-L101). This fix will be part of the upcoming 17.3 release.

Comment: And the explicit version works because it only evaluates `Derived` when running the code instead of when generating the class?

Comment: @Niobos: exactly, you explicitly named `Derived`, which is looked up as a global each time the method is called, and that is bound to the new generated class.

Comment: Anyone knows if there are plans to "fix" this in CPython too for `@dataclass(slots=True)`?

Comment: @MEE see: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/107391