# TypeError when calling super() in dataclass(slots=True) subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, python-dataclasses, slots

I am trying to call a a superclass method from a dataclass with `slots=True` in Python 3.10.5.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(slots=True)
class Base:
    def hi(self):
        print("Hi")


@dataclass(slots=True)
class Sub(Base):
    def hi(self):
        super().hi()


Sub().hi()
```

I get the following error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 16, in <module>
    Sub().hi()
  File "...", line 13, in hi
    super().hi()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

It works fine if I remove `slots=True` from `Sub`, or make it a non-dataclass with `__slots__` manually. The error remains if I instead do these to `Base`.

`Sub.__mro__` is `(<class '__main__.Sub'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>)` and `isinstance(Sub(), Base)` is `True`.

Comment: You may have the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159210/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-explicit-supercl-self-with-slots) using the 0-argument form of `super()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46159416/14978104), the dataclass decorator creates a new class object, and so the `__closure__` attached to `hi()` is different to the one attached to the decorated class, and therefore the `super()` call cannot work without arguments due to relying on the `__closure__`.

Therefore, you need to change `super().hi()` to `super(Sub, self).hi()`.