# TypeError when using super() in a dataclass with slots=True

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, slots

I have a dataclass with (kind of) a getter method.

This code works as expected:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass()
class A:
    def get_data(self):
        # get some values from object's fields
        # do some calculations
        return "a calculated value"

@dataclass()
class B(A):
    def get_data(self):
        data = super().get_data()
        return data + " (modified)"


b = B()

print(b.get_data())  # a calculated value (modified)
```

However, if I add `slots=True`, I get a `TypeError`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=True)
class A:
    def get_data(self):
        return "a calculated value"

@dataclass(slots=True)
class B(A):
    def get_data(self):
        data = super().get_data()
        return data + " (modified)"


b = B()

print(b.get_data())  # TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

The error vanishes if I use the old-style super(), contrary to [pep-3135](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=True)
class A:
    def get_data(self):
        return "a calculated value"

@dataclass(slots=True)
class B(A):
    def get_data(self):
        data = super(B, self).get_data()
        return data + " (modified)"


b = B()

print(b.get_data())  # a calculated value (modified)
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it the right way?

Comment: *"`slots`: [..]  `__slots__` attribute will be generated __and new class will be returned instead of the original one__"* — https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass. So it does mess with the class when you use `slots`.

Comment: @deceze so when I specify `B` explicitly in `super(B, self)`, is this the new class or the original one?

Comment: It's the new class. `B` is not looked up until `get_data` is *called*, by which time the name has been rebound to the new class. When `super` has no arguments, the class used as its "default" argument is determined while the class is being defined, *before* that class gets passed to `dataclass` to be replaced.

Comment: (It's not entirely clear to me how to *prove* this via inspection of `B`, though. )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError when calling super() in dataclass(slots=True) subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268995/typeerror-when-calling-super-in-dataclassslots-true-subclass)

Comment: @user202729 it does, although deceze's answer is more thorough. It also links to the earlier question about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46159210/3091161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `slots`: If true (the default is `False`), `__slots__` attribute will be generated **and new class will be returned instead of the original one.** If `__slots__` is already defined in the class, then `TypeError` is raised.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass

Taking this as an example:

```
@dataclass(slots=True)
class Foo:
    pass
```

This means this works something like this:

```
class Foo:
    pass

Foo = dataclass(slots=True)(Foo)
```

You define a class `Foo`, and then it gets replaced with a *different*, altered class.

Now, your method:

```
def get_data(self):
    data = super().get_data()
    ...
```

This `super()` was written in the original `Foo` class and will assume it's supposed to look up the parent of this original `Foo` class; but the instance it currently has is not actually an instance of that class, it's an instance of the other, altered class.

When you do this instead:

```
data = super(Foo, self).get_data()
```

This looks up what *currently* refers to the name `Foo`, which again matches what `self` also refers to at this moment.