# python inheritance and super keyword

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I am unable to understand this code snippet.

```
class First():  
  def __init__(self):  
    super(First, self).__init__()  
    print("first")  

class Second():  
  def __init__(self):  
    super(Second, self).__init__()  
    print("second")  

class Third(Second, First):  
  def __init__(self):  
    super(Third, self).__init__()  
    print("third")  

Third();
```

and the output is :

```
first  
second  
third
```

It seems that constructor of each is called in reverse order of base classes `First.__init__()` then `Second.__init__()`
How is `super(Third, self).__init__()` this statement working.

Answer (score 1):

You called `super()` before you print, so yes, only after `super()` *returns* will your `print()` expressions be reached.

Your class Method Resolution Order (MRO) is:

```
>>> Third.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Third'>, <class '__main__.Second'>, <class '__main__.First'>, <class 'object'>)
```

so creating `Third()` then results in:

```
Third.__init__()
    super(Third, self).__init__()
        Second.__init__()                   # next in the MRO for Third
            super(Second, self).__init__()
                First.__init__()            # next in the MRO for Third
                    super(First, self).__init__()
                        object.__init__()   # next in the MRO for Third
                            return
                    print("first")
                    return
            print("second")
            return
    print("third")
    return
```

so the code outputs `first`, `second`, then `third`, but the methods were called in the opposite order.

Side note: [`super()` is a *type of object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), not a keyword. `super()` is just another expression (albeit one that [causes some side effects during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic)).