# Second parameter of super()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, super

A colleague of mine wrote code analogous to the following today, asked me to have a look, and it took me a while to spot the mistake:

```
class A():                                                                                         
    def __init__(self):                                                         
        print('A')                                                              

class B(A):                                                                     
    def __init__(self):                                                         
        super(B).__init__()                                               

b = B()
```

The problem here is that there's no `self` parameter to `super()` in `B`'s constructor. What surprised me is that absolutely nothing happens in this case, i.e. no error, nothing. What does the `super` object created by `super(B)` contain? As an object, it clearly has a constructor, so that's what gets called, but how is that object related to `B`? In particular, why is this valid code and doesn't throw an exception somewhere? Is `super(B)` an object with some actual use and what would that be?

Comment: Are you in Python 2 or 3?

Comment: The documentation on [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) states that omitting the second argument causes it to create an unbound object

Comment: What's even more odd is that calling `super(B).__init__()` only works inside of a method of `B` (or a subclass of `B`). Calling `super(B).__init__()` outside of a class throws `RuntimeError: super(): no arguments`

Comment: [Here's](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236278) a very nice article about unbound super objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing that causes all these ambiguities is that "why `obj = super(B).__init__()` works?". That's because `super(B).__self_class__` returns `None` and in that case you're calling the `None` objects' `__init__` like following which returns None:

```
In [40]: None.__init__()
```

Regarding the rest of the cases, you can simply check the difference by calling the `super`'s essential attributes in both cases:

```
In [36]: class B(A):                                                                     
        def __init__(self):                                                         
                obj = super(B, self)
                print(obj.__class__)
                print(obj.__thisclass__)
                print(obj.__self_class__)
                print(obj.__self__)
   ....:         

In [37]: b = B()
<class 'super'>
<class '__main__.B'>
<class '__main__.B'>
<__main__.B object at 0x7f15a813f940>

In [38]: 

In [38]: class B(A):                                                                     
        def __init__(self):                                                         
                obj = super(B)
                print(obj.__class__)
                print(obj.__thisclass__)
                print(obj.__self_class__)
                print(obj.__self__)
   ....:         

In [39]: b = B()
<class 'super'>
<class '__main__.B'>
None
None
```

For the rest of the things I recommend you to read the documentation thoroughly. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super and this article by Raymond Hettinger https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/.

Moreover, If you want to know why `super(B)` doesn't work outside of the class and generally why calling the `super()` without any argument works inside a class you can read This comprehensive answer by Martijn https://stackoverflow.com/a/19609168/2867928.

**A short description of the solution:**

As mentioned in the comments by @Nathan Vērzemnieks you need to call the initializer once to get the `super()` object work. The reason is laid behind the magic of new `super` object that is explained in aforementioned links.

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print("finally!")
   ...:

In [2]: class B(A):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         sup = super(B)
   ...:         print("Before: {}".format(sup))
   ...:         sup.__init__()
   ...:         print("After: {}".format(sup))
   ...:         sup.__init__()
   ...:

In [3]: B()
Before: <super: <class 'B'>, NULL>
After: <super: <class 'B'>, <B object>>
finally!
```

Comment: @Rawing Isn't that explained in https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/?

Comment: @Rawing That's strongly related to the magic of `super()` in python 3.X which can be called without arguments inside a class. Here is a question regard this very topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic that is answered nicely by Martijn.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that only applies to the 0-argument form of `super`. Anyway, I'll stop pestering you (sorry about that!) and post a new question about it. Let's clean up this mess, shall we?

Comment: I don't think it's true that `super(B).__init__()` is calling `None.__init__()`. See this gist for evidence to the contrary: https://gist.github.com/njvrzm/358f96c971a2adc329bcc1d860bede2a

Comment: Actually I've copied the code from that gist to [my answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48332210/9200529).

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Well that's after calling the initializer once! All I was explained was that when you don't pass the `self` to the `super()` the `__self_class__` is None and therefore, there's nothing to be called. But as it's explained in aforementioned links the solution is what you did. You have to call the initializer manually once! (the magic of super)

Comment: My point is, you say `super(B).__init__()` calls `None.__init__()` but it doesn't - it calls super's initializer twice! Once as part of `super(B)` and once explicitly. `None.__init__` has no part in it.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks I know, but [`__self_class__` is the type of the instance invoking `super()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce5b0e9db1b9698e6ffc43ae41cf3a22ca5a6ba6/Objects/typeobject.c#L7454) which before calling the `__init__` is None, as mentioned in documentation as well.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure who's misunderstanding what here, but I'll try one more approach: when you call `__init__` on an unbound super like you get from `super(B)`, no delegation happens: you're calling `super.__init__`. If it were otherwise, if it was actually calling `None.__init__`, the "before" and "after" outputs from my code would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion here comes from the fact that (in a class definition context) `super()` gives a bound `super` object which then delegates `__init__` to its `__self_class__`, while `super(B)` creates an unbound `super` object which, because its `__self_class__` is `None`, does *not* delegate.

```
In [41]: class Test(int):
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         print(super().__self_class__)
    ...:         print(super().__init__)
    ...:         print(super(Test).__self_class__)
    ...:         print(super(Test).__init__)
    ...:

In [42]: Test()
<class '__main__.Test'>
<method-wrapper '__init__' of Test object at 0x10835c9c8>
None
<method-wrapper '__init__' of super object at 0x10835c3c8>
```

So when you call `super(B).__init__()`, it creates an unbound `super` but then immediately calls `__init__` on it; that, because of the magic described in the various links [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48302929/9200529), binds that unbound `super`. There are no references to it, so it disappears, but that's what's happening under the hood.