# Does any magic happen when I call `super(some_cls)`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

While investigating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48302139/1222951), I came across this strange behavior of single-argument `super`:

*Calling `super(some_class).__init__()` works inside of a method of `some_class` (or a subclass thereof), but throws an exception when called anywhere else.*

Code sample:

```
class A():                                                                                         
    def __init__(self):                                                         
        super(A).__init__()  # doesn't throw exception

a = A()
super(A).__init__()  # throws exception
```

The exception being thrown is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 8, in <module>
    super(A).__init__() # throws exception
RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

---

I don't understand why the location of the call makes a difference.

It's well-known that the zero-argument form of `super` [performs magic](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#super):

> The zero argument form only works inside a class definition, as the compiler fills in the necessary details to correctly retrieve the class being defined, as well as accessing the current instance for ordinary methods.

However, no such statement exists for the one-argument form of `super`. On the contrary:

> Also note that, aside from the zero argument form, super() is not limited to use inside methods.

---

So, my question is, what exactly is happening under the hood? Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: @MrName Oops, sorry about that. It throws `RuntimeError: super(): no arguments`. I've added the traceback to the question.

Comment: hmmm I wonder if it's looking for a 'self' in the local variables. you have to supply it in 2.7 but it is inferred in 3, via closure-style mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, `super(A)` gives an unbound super object. When you call `__init__()` on that, it's being called with no arguments. When `super.__init__` is called with no arguments, the compiler tries to infer the arguments: (from typeobject.c line 7434, latest source)

```
static int
super_init(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    superobject *su = (superobject *)self;
    PyTypeObject *type = NULL;
    PyObject *obj = NULL;
    PyTypeObject *obj_type = NULL;

    if (!_PyArg_NoKeywords("super", kwds))
        return -1;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "|O!O:super", &PyType_Type, &type, &obj))
        return -1;

    if (type == NULL) {
        /* Call super(), without args -- fill in from __class__
           and first local variable on the stack. */
```

A few lines later: (ibid, line 7465)

```
    f = PyThreadState_GET()->frame;
...
    co = f->f_code;
...
    if (co->co_argcount == 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                        "super(): no arguments");
        return -1;
    }
```

When you call `super(A)`, this inferring behavior is bypassed because type is not None. When you then call `__init__()` on the unbound super - because it isn't bound, this `__init__` call isn't proxied - the type argument *is* None and the compiler attempts to infer. Inside the class definition, the self argument is present and is used for this purpose. Outside, no arguments are available, so the exception is raised.

In other words, `super(A)` is *not* behaving differently depending on where it is called - it's `super.__init__()` that's behaving differently, and that's exactly what the documentation suggests.

Comment: I see, my mistake was to assume that arguments were being inserted into `super.__new__`, when in reality they're being inserted into `super.__init__`.Thank you for the fantastic answer!

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for the fascinating prompt.

Answer (score 1):

(Note - I've substantially edited this answer to be more relevant to the actual question.)

If you call `sup = super(A); sup.__init__()`, the result is exactly the same as if you'd called `sup = super()`: inside a class definition, you  get a bound super; outside, you get a RuntimeError (the reason for which is in my other answer).

Here's a snippet for corroboration:

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print("finally!")
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: class B(A):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         noarg = super()
   ...:         print("No-arg super: {}".format(noarg))
   ...:         onearg = super(B) # creates unbound super
   ...:         print("One-arg before: {}".format(onearg))
   ...:         onearg.__init__() # initializes sup as if sup = super()
   ...:         print("One-arg after: {}".format(onearg))
   ...:         onearg.__init__() # calls B.__init__()
   ...:

In [2]: B()
No-arg super: <super: <class 'B'>, <B object>>
One-arg before: <super: <class 'B'>, NULL>
One-arg after: <super: <class 'B'>, <B object>>
finally!
```

Comment: Note that calling `super(A)` is not exactly the same as `super()`. `super(A).__init__()` doesn't do anything, but somehow the exception is muted.

Comment: I'm not saying `super(A)` is the same as `super()`. I'm saying `super(A).__init__()` is the same as `super()`. See the new sample output at the bottom of the edited answer.