# an example about C3

Tags: python, python-3.x, method-resolution-order

I got the following code from github about MRO and C3, and I don't quite understand the the last three lines, and what the difference among super().foo(), super(B,self).foo() and super(C,self).foo() in python3.x, code as follows:

```
class A(object):

    def foo(self):
        print('foo of A')

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):

    def foo(self):
        print('foo fo C')

class D(B, C):
    pass

class E(D):

    def foo(self):
        print('foo in E')
        super().foo()
        super(B, self).foo()
        super(C, self).foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = D()
    d.foo()
    e = E()
    e.foo()
```

the expected and actual results is as follow:

```
foo fo C
foo in E
foo fo C
foo fo C
foo of A
```

Comment: here's `E.__mro__`: ```(<class 'SO54756219.E'>, <class 'SO54756219.D'>, <class 'SO54756219.B'>, <class 'SO54756219.C'>, <class 'SO54756219.A'>, <class 'object'>)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the form `super()` in Python 3 is really the same thing as `super(<CurrentClass>, self)`, where the Python compiler [provides enough information for `super()` to determine what the correct class to use is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic/19609168#19609168). So in `E.foo()`, `super().foo()` can be read as `super(E, self).foo()`.

To understand what is going on, you need to look at the [`class.__mro__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__):

> This attribute is a tuple of classes that are considered when looking for base classes during method resolution.

It is this tuple that shows you what the C3 *Method Resolution Order* is for any given class hierarchy. For your class `E`, that order is:

```
>>> E.__mro__
(<class '__main__.E'>, <class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> for cls in E.__mro__:  # print out just the names, for easier readability.
...     print(cls.__name__)
...
E
D
B
C
A
object
```

The `super()` object bases everything off from that ordered sequence of classes. The call

```
super(SomeClass, self).foo()
```

results in the following series of steps:

- The `super()` object retrieves the `self.__mro__` tuple.
- `super()` locates the index for the `SomeClass` class in that tuple.
- Accessing the `foo` attribute on the `super()` object triggers a search for a class that has a `foo` attribute on the MRO, **starting at the next index after the `SomeClass` index**.
- If the attribute found this way is a [descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) binds the attribute found this way to `self`. Functions are descriptors, binding produces a bound method, and this is how Python passes in the `self` reference when you call a method.

Expressed as simplified Python code that ignores edge cases and other uses for `super()`,  that would look like:

```
class Super:
    def __init__(self, type_, obj_or_type):
        self.mro = obj_or_type.__mro__
        self.idx = self.mro.index(type_) + 1
        self.obj_or_type = obj_or_type
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        for cls in self.mro[self.idx:]:
            attrs = vars(cls)
            if name in attrs:
                result = attrs[name]
                if hasattr(result, '__get__'):
                    result = result.__get__(obj_or_type, type(self.obj_or_type))
                return result
        raise AttributeError(name)
```

Combining those two pieces of information, you can see what happens when you call `e.foo()`:

- `print('foo in E')` is executed, resulting in *foo in E*
- `super().foo()` is executed, effectively the same thing as `super(E, self).foo()`.

  - The MRO is searched, starting at the next index *past* `E`, so at `D` (no `foo` attribute), moving on to `B` (no `foo` attribute), then `C` (attribute found). `C.foo` is returned, bound to `self`.
  - `C.foo(self)` is called, resulting in *foo fo C*
- `super(B, self).foo()` is executed.

  - The MRO is searched, starting at the next index *past* `B`, so at `C` (attribute found). `C.foo` is returned, bound to `self`.
  - `C.foo(self)` is called, resulting in *foo fo C*
- `super(C, self).foo()` is executed.

  - The MRO is searched, starting at the next index *past* `C`, so at `A` (attribute found). `A.foo` is returned, bound to `self`.
  - `A.foo(self)` is called, resulting in *foo of A*