# Why do I get "AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__del__'" when calling the destructor of super from my Thread subclass' destructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructor, superclass

In my Python (3.6) program, I have a thread object, like so:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        ...

    def __del__(self):
        ...
        super(type(self), self).__del__()

    def run(self):
        ...
```

used in the main program like this:

```
def main():
    my_thread = MyThread()
    my_thread.start()
    ...
    my_thread.join()
```

But as soon as I try to run this program, I get the following Python crash:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method MyThread.__del__ of <MyThread(Thread-6, stopped 1234)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/my_proj/my_program.py", line 123, in __del__
  super(type(self), self).__del__()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__del__'
```

Why is this, and how can it be fixed?

Is it not allowed to call the `__del__()` method of super explicitly like this, or what? (Google seems to tell me otherwise, but still won't give me any answer to why this happens)

Comment: `super(type(self), self)` is *always* wrong. In Python 3, you can simply use `super()`. That said, if if the superclass has no `__del__` then you'll get this `AttributeError`.

Comment: Why did you use `super(MyThread, self).__init__()` but then `super(type(self), self).__del__()` ? Use the same (correct) form of super everywhere.  Either `super(MyThread, self)`, or `super()`.  BTW, `__del__` is often more trouble than it is worth. It isn't guaranteed to be called.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think it sounds like a very strange design that objects (the "base Object class" in Python or whatever) can lack a destructor completely (and not just have an empty one) when it is a reserved name and everything, and thus cause this kind of errors!? Are you completely sure that this simple explanation is correct? (in that case please post it as a real answer too, and I will mark it as such if no one seems to disagree with it!)

Comment: @NedBatchelder The different forms were just a remnant from desperately trying to find the solution to the problem myself, sorry about that. BUT, when attempting to use only "super()" in the constructor as you recommend, I get the following error when trying to run it: RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called

Comment: You can prove to yourself that instances of `object` have not `__del__` by looking at the result returned from `dir(object())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`super(type(self), self)` is *always* wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4883822/119527). In Python 2, you must explicitly name the current class, e.g. `super(MyThread, self)`. In Python 3, you can simply use `super()`:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

    def run(self):
        # ...
```

That said, if if the superclass has no `__del__` then you'll get this `AttributeError`. If your base classes have no `__del__` you can simply omit it. There is rarely a good reason to implement `__del__` in your class.

If you need controlled cleanup, consider using implementing a *context manager*.

Comment: Ok, thanks. About your recommendation about using "super()" instead though: When I try this in the constructor I just get the following error when trying to run the program: `RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called`? Does this mean that your recommendation is wrong, or why does this happen otherwise?

Comment: Hmm, it gets even fishier... When I try to use only `super()` in the destructor, I do NOT get the `AttributeError` (contrary to what you write here above in your answer)? Any ideas/comments?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow: FWIW when I create a class with a base class of `object` that also has a `__del__` method that calls `super().__del__()`, I **do** get `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__del__'` when I try to delete an instance of it.

Comment: @Jonathon: To say that the two argument form of a `super` call is _always_ wrong is simply not true—it may be unnecessary, but it will work and does so correctly.

Comment: @martineau It's not the fact that he's using the two-argument version, it's that he's passing `type(self)` for the first argument. (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4883822/119527)  If it were that easy, `super` could do that itself. The problem is, if you are in the middle of a class hierarchy, `type(self)` is *not* the current class, it's the most-derived. I think it might lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: @Jonathon: Thanks for the explanation. I do agree that using `type(self)` in a `super()` call is always wrong (in both Python 2 and 3).

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Your `__init__` should start with `super().__init__()`

Comment: @QuestionOverflow `__del__` isn't even guaranteed to be called. Please do the following to convince yourself that *there is no `Thread.__del__` implementation*, so your efforts to implement `__del__` yourself, and call the base class implementation are futile. Open the Python shell, and `import threading; t = threading.Thread(); t.__del__` (see `AttributeError`)

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood your recommendation to _"simply use `super()`"_ when you really meant `super().__init__()` and `super().__del__()`, and your proof that Object and Thread lacks `__del__()` thus works and makes sense. Your answer is now accepted and upvoted.